# Selection of parameters in Diffie-Hellman

Tags: c, gmp, diffie-hellman

maybe it's not so proper to ask this question here... anyway, I'm trying to use the gmp library for the implementation of DH, but the problem here I got is:

Once, when I was doing the tests to observe the output, although big values of prime and the private keys were selected:

- p was about more than 300 digits long in decimal
- a, b were about 100 digits long

finally I got a shared secret key which was extremely small, perhaps smaller than 10^8 in decimal...

This problem didn't show up many times, in fact, during all the observation, it appeared just once...but still, this was not so good at all.

So I wonder if there are some methods which can avoid this... Thanx a lot

Comment: Edited for English. IMO, this is an OK question for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Diffie-Hellman key exchange is designed to generate a secret shared key.

By using large values of p, a and b, you ensure that the pool of potential shared keys is a very large one.

However, the *actual* value of the shared key can be **any** value within that pool. As a result, it could range from zero to (p - 1)... that's because, the Key is

`G^(ab) mod p`

Hence, you haven't discovered a problem here... your just seeing the instances when `G^(ab)` is close in value to a multiple of `p`, and hence the `mod` is a low number.

Comment: In other words, the shared key *is* quite long, but many of the first digits happen to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the point of D-H is that the secret key could be *any* value within the range specified by p. At least in theory, eliminating some of those possibilities would make it less secure, not more so (realistically, as long as you leave a sufficiently large pool of keys, it makes little real difference).

It is true that *if* an attacker decided to try key-exhaustion (brute-force) attack, and started from 0 and just counted up, they'd hit this one relatively soon. Then again, if you decided on some other lower bound and (for example) re-negotiated the key if it was below that bound, it wouldn't do any real good -- instead of starting at 0, the attacker would start at the specified lower bound, and you'd have gained nothing.